# Gradle Startup Failed : unexpected token: ... @ line 83, column 7

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

I'm attempting to build my game in Unity3D and I get the following error:

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\Program Files\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Armani\Documents\1st App Alpha\MyAppAlpha\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle' line: 83
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'D:\Armani\Documents\1st App Alpha\MyAppAlpha\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle'.

  > startup failed:
  >   build file 'D:\Armani\Documents\1st App Alpha\MyAppAlpha\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle': 83: unexpected token: ... @ line 83, column 7.
  >          ...
  >          ^

  1 error

I was attempting to fix a multidex error and I was also fixing the brackets in all my gradle build files when I came across it not even starting the gradle build. This is showing up in my temp folder so I do not know what to fix for the issue.

This is where the "..." occurs in my temp gradle:

android {
      ...
     defaultConfig {
             ...
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
      dexOptions {
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      }
  ...
  }

Comment: This is not the solution you want maybe, but I had these same problems so I stopped using gradle and started using internal building system provided by Unity, it works fine

Comment: Give it a try..

Comment: Most of the links I've searched having errors with Gradle have always mentioned that using the Internal Building System has helped them. I've been set on using Gradle but if I can't find a different solution I may just switch. I'll try importing my assets first to see if it fixes anything before attempting the switch.

Comment: Nope, switching to Internal is giving me different errors. I guess I'll try and fix those and see which one I get stuck on more.